# Function / setInterval unexpectedly logging twice to the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a callback to my Web API to collect new race data, I've created a `setInterval` and tested it to see if it does log to the console once as I would expect but for some reason the console is logging twice. I don't understand why.

I am wanting to remove the `console.log()` inside the if statement and replace that with a call to the server but if it's logging twice i'll receive twice as much information.

```
var TimeOutID = '';

var TenRaces = 0;

var StartThis = function () {
    console.log("Starting run");

    //Simulate counting down to next race
    TimeOut = new Date().getTime() + 5000;

    $('#next').countdown(TimeOut, function (event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
        if(event.elapsed) {
            //once the countdown timer has elapsed fetch data
            console.log("Race: " + TenRaces); // <-- this one is logged twice
        }
    });

    //loop ten races simulating ten different times data is needed
    TenRaces++;
    if (TenRaces > 10) {
        clearInterval(TimeOutID);
    }

};

TimeOutID = setInterval(StartThis, 6000);
```

Why is `console.log()` running and logging twice?

I'm using the jQuery plugin from http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Comment: Is it just twice or, 1, 2, 3.... every time??

Comment: It always logs twice on every loop

Comment: You have two `console.log`s in your `StartThis` function, which one is running twice?

Comment: the one inside the event.elapsed if statement.

Comment: How many `$('#next')` elements do you have? Log this to find out: `$('#next').length`

Comment: And is the double logging happening straight away?

Comment: I only have the one $('#next') element and yes the logging is happening immediately one after the other.

Comment: @AdrianLynch With the id-selector, even if there were more than one elements, jQuery would only use the first in the result set.

Comment: @Yoshi - Not true. Selecting more than one element with the same ID still selects them all. It then falls on `countdown` as to whether it works on all elements or just one.

Comment: So because it's in the callback for `countdown`, you should find out if there's a reason the callback is being called twice. Console log the `event` to see if that gives you any clues.

Comment: @AdrianLynch [Sure?](https://jsfiddle.net/346pq2jh/1/)

Comment: @Yoshi - Well I was sure until you showed me that! :P

Comment: @AdrianLynch has nailed it. After the timer has elapsed it fires an event called 'finish' and the last event 'stoped' (spelt that way). So all i've done is listen for the finish event which has now solved it.

many thanks

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the elapsed mode is deliberately designed to continue after the countdown has finished. Therefore I think it's looping twice before the TenRaces var iterates. It would just keep logging forever if you didn't iterate that var.

Do the log/fetch data on the finish.countdown event instead, this triggers just once, when the countdown finishes. See documentation:

[countdown documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#event-object)

E.g.

```
$('div#clock').countdown(finalDate)
.on('finish.countdown', callback);
```

Comment: That's had an even stranger result, it now logs out once for race 1, logs twice for race two, three times for race three etc....

'$('#next').countdown(TimeOut).on('finish.countdown', function () {
                    console.log("Race: " + TenRaces);
                });'